# how to position one div on the left and two divs to the right

Tags: css, html

i have this `main_window` div which is 800px wide, and 550 px height, then there is two divs that should be next to it, troubleshooting_area and timeline div, those two make up for the 550 in height but need to be floating to the right of the main window
the two divs below should be next to the main window, how can i achieve that??

here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/S8RC3/3/

```
<div class="appview_fullscreen app_ama">
 <center><strong>Auto Mechanics Alliance</strong> </br>
    <i>let us come together and become one</i>
 </center>
<div class="main_area">
    <div class="tabs_area">

    </div>
    <div class="main_window">

    </div>
    <div class="troubleshoot_area">

    </div>
    <div class="timeline">

    </div>
 </div>


</div>


body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
.appview_fullscreen
{
    width: 1005px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px;
}
.main_area
{
    border: 2px solid green;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.tabs_area
{
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 20px;
}

.main_window
{
    min-height: 550px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 2px 1px 1px 1px;
}
.troubleshoot_area
{
    border: 1px dotted green;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.timeline
{
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 350px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, I would simply add:

```
position: absolute;
top: 76px;
left: 808px;
```

to your `.timeline` and `.troubleshoot-area` classes.

You can see an updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/S8RC3/4/

Comment: i guess this is it, i mean my application aint supposed to resize as it is the large desktop version, so i guess this isnt bad thanks

Comment: No problem, if you're satisfied with my answer, please click the checkmark under this post, on the left. (I think it's right below the arrows). This will accept it as correct.

Comment: im confused, if i float this elements in two wrappers, and i start resizing the window isnt the float gonna act weird and try to move below when one cant fit??

Comment: I'm not 100% certain what it is you're asking, however if you have a different question, then I encourage you to start a new one. If you're confused about CSS positioning, this is an excellent guide that should help clear things up: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Answer (score 0):

Try these ways.

CSS

```
body
{
    width: 99%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
.appview_fullscreen
{
    width: 1005px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px;
}
.main_area
{
    border: 2px solid green;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.tabs_area
{
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 20px;
}

.main_window
{
    min-height: 550px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 2px 1px 1px 1px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.troubleshoot_area
{
    border: 1px dotted green;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 76px;
    left: 808px;
}
.timeline
{
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 350px;
    width: 200px;
    float:right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 76px;
    left: 808px;
}
```

[DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8RC3/11/)